# Error Message in Arista Transcoder, how to install ffdeinterlace plugin?

Tags: apt, ffmpeg, arista-transcoder

I keep getting this error message when I want to transcode a dvd into say an `avi` file format. This is the error message I get:

```
Required plugin could not be found
Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to support the following multimedia feature:
  GStreamer element ffdeinterlace
```

I don't know what to do. I have already done the following:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.*
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5_amd64.deb
```

None has been able to fix the problem.  If anyone can help, it would sure help myself and most likely many people that just want to back up their movies.

Comment: Or dog gone it, encourage someone with it like a mix tape back in the 80's.

Comment: Try using this PPA for gstreamer: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/gstffmpeg-keep You would be best to remove your original gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5_amd64.deb

Comment: Further to @andrew.46's comment, there is a known bug, posted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arista/+bug/1306592

Answer (score 1):

Source: [arista](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/arista)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

and then restart arista.